# Problem build cordova app with cordova-plugin-qrscanner

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have installed cordova-plugin-qrscanner in an (old) cordova application.
The installation works correctly but when I try to build the app for Android, the console outputs errors like those

```
[javac] Compiling 5 source files to C:\Users\christian.benseler\dev\testemob\platforms\android\ant-build\classes
    [javac] C:\Users\christian.benseler\dev\testemob\platforms\android\src\com\bitpay\cordova\qrscanner\QRScanner.java:27: error: package android.support.v4.app does not exist
    [javac] import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] C:\Users\christian.benseler\dev\testemob\platforms\android\src\com\bitpay\cordova\qrscanner\QRScanner.java:356: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]                     boolean showRationale = ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(cordova.getActivity(), permission);
```

it seems my android sdk is missing something, but I cannot figure out what. The readme from the repo does not specify anything about requirements, and I do not have full expertise in configuring Android/Java applications with its dependencies. Anyone can help me to find out what is missing in my environment?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the plugin is missing a dependency to android support v4, as that's the one that contains `ActivityCompat` class
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat